# Confusing error message from git

Tags: git, github

I got this message from Git:

> You asked to pull from the remote 'origin', but did not specify
>   a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
>   for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.

Can anyone explain it? and more important how to fix it?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You have to tell git which branch you want to pull from the "origin" remote repos.

I guess you want the default branch (master) so `git pull origin master` should fix your problem.

See `git help branch`, `git help pull` and `git help fetch`  for more informations.

Comment: to make it work I had to checkout "master" branch (there was no branch selected) and pull, that fixed the problem.

Comment: @cinek: Yes, `git pull` pulls and merges with the *current branch* so its behavior completely depends on what branch is checked out, and with a detached HEAD (no branch checked out), there's no way it can know what branch to pull.

Comment: @cinek: I supposed you were new to git so I admit that you were in a totally standard state on branch master, my bad :-).

Answer (score 104):

To fix it, assuming you are on the `master` branch and want to pull the `master` branch from the `origin` remote, in new enough Git versions (1.8 or newer):

```
git branch -u origin/master master
```

(Analogously for other branches and/or remotes.)

If you can combine this with a push, it’s even shorter:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Thereafter, a plain `git pull`/`git push` will do what you expect.

---

During the Git 1.7 series, `git branch` didn’t have the `-u` switch (only `git push` did), and instead you had to use the much longer `--set-upstream`:

```
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

Note the reversal of arguments compared to `-u`. I fumbled this order more than once.

---

All of these, by the way, are shorthands for doing the following, which you can still do explicitly:

```
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

Before 1.7, you *had* to do it this way.

Comment: I think that the command at the top (at least in my version of Git) sets the upstream of a branch called "origin" to be "origin/master".

If your branch locally is called "master" I think you would want:
`git branch --set-upstream master origin/master`

Comment: Interestingly, the `-u` option is undocumented for `git branch` in my version, 1.8.5.3, making your documentation of it here even more important. And, as you note, the option was unavailable in version 1.7.*. Since `-u` is short for `--set-upstream`, shouldn't the order of its arguments be reversed as you did for `--set-upstream` due to @EvanDonovan's comment?

Comment: However, when I use the command you show (`git branch -u origin/master master`) it works as expected/intended for me: "Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin."

Comment: @hobs: that is actually a perversity of Git. The `-u` switch is actually *not* the short form of `--set-upstream`. Its order of arguments is effectively reversed from the order for `--set-upstream`. I think it was only later that `--set-upstream-to` (note the “-to”) was introduced, which is what `-u` is now actually the short form of.

Comment: Wow! Confusing indeed. Thanks for untangling that for me.

Answer (score 5):

Message says exactly what it is about. Your current branch is not associated with (is not tracking) any branch in *origin*. So git doesn't know what to pull.

What to do? That depends...

In most usual situation you are working off some local branch *xyz* which branched from *master* which is cloned from *origin*'s master. The usual way to resolve it is to switch to *master* and pull to synchronize it with *origin* and then come back to *xyz* and `rebase master`.

But in your situation you might want to do something else. We can't know it without knowing details of your branches and remotes and how you intent to use them.

Comment: I get tripped up with this when I create a local branch off `master`/`main` but haven't pushed it to the remote.  If I'm on the new branch and do a pull I get this message.